# Showing the form input data in the list

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I have tried multiple ways in order to make my code works but I failed. I want to make the input text of the form show up in the list(id="contact") after submit it, like adding a new contact on a contact list. This is my code, I really appreciated your help!

my HTML:

```
<div> 
<ul id="contactlist" class=ppl>
    <ol id="demo"></ol>
    <li id="pplli"><img id="wetalk" class="talkbox" src="img/talkbox.png"><p class="contactname">Aiden</p> </li>
    <li id="pplli"> <img id="wetalk1" class="talkbox" src="img/talkbox.png">Jaimie </li>
    <li id="pplli"><img id="wetalk2" class="talkbox" src="img/talkbox.png">Jimmy</li>
    <br>

    <buttom id="clearBtn" style="position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:0px;"></buttom>

    <br>

    <a href="#addform" class="ui-btn" id="add"><img id="plus" src="img/plus.png"></a>
</ul>
</div>

<section id="addform">
    <form name="myform" id="myform">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" class="myfname" placeholder="ex : Jen" name="fname" required><br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" class="mylname" placeholder="ex : Shen" name="lname" required ><br>
        <label for="pname">Phone:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="pname" class="mypname" placeholder="ex : 333-333-333" name="pname" required >
    <input type='button' onclick='addName' class="btn" value='Submit' />

    </form>
</section>
```

This is my javascript:

```
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

    function addName(){
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var entry = document.createElement("li");
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fname));
    demo.appendChild(entry);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: remember that when you want to call functions the syntax has to make provision for a way to pass arguments, () is how that is generally done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you are doing wrong is

change

```
  <input type='button' onclick='addName' class="btn" value='Submit' />
```

to

```
 <input type='button' onclick='addName()' class="btn" value='Submit' />
```

you need to pass your function name with ().

Hope this helps!